# regEx function not does not pass test

Tags: javascript, regex

Just wondering what could be wrong with my regEx function, is returning false, is there a better or cleaner approach to mimic startsWith as my application has an embedded JS engine that is ecma 1.8.5 spidermonkey

```js
function startsWith(i,s) {
  var regEx = new RegExp("/^"+i+"/");
  console.log(regEx)
  return regEx.test(s);
}


const myString = "hello world";

console.log(startsWith("hello",myString));
```

**update**
Is failing to test when special characters in strings also.

> startsWith("%^&.h",myString)

Comment: I think just like this `var regEx = new RegExp("^"+i);` without the `/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to achieve this without regex:

```js
function startsWith(i,s) {
  return s.indexOf(i) === 0;
}

const myString = "hello world";

console.log(startsWith("hello",myString));
```

Comment: This fails, because the function needs to test the string starts with the criteria.

Comment: Testing if the index is exactly zero only returns true if it starts with the given string.

Comment: Okey it seems to work, but how? i thought indexOf would search the complete fisrt word? it is also working with special characters which is good `const myString = "!£$heello world";`

Comment: Just think of the string as an arbitrary array of characters. You’re just testing if the pattern appears within the string and that it occurs at index zero for the first character.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the corrected startsWith function:

```
function startsWith(i, s) {
  var regEx = new RegExp("^" + i);
  return regEx.test(s);
}
```

Comment: The question says they're using EcmaScript 1.8.5. The built-in `startsWith` was added in ES6.

Comment: Oh yeah I kept focusing on the code

Comment: it fails when there are special characters in the string https://jsfiddle.net/ackL2h4t/